# What does the integrand in a double integral represent?

Tags: integration

I see this problem and I'm not sure what the integrand here represents. Can someone tell me what it visually represents here?

[image]

Comment: If the value of the integral is the mass of the shape, it's the density at the point $(x,y)$.

Comment: The integrand can represent many of the things that the integrand of a single integral can, as long as it can be properly reinterpreted to fit a two-dimensional domain (some things are difficult to transfer, such as the integral of velocity being position, that one doesn't readily go up a dimension).

Comment: so at point 0,0, why is the integrand 1?

Answer (score -1):

Let $$S=\iint f(x,y)dxdy$$

When $ f(x,y)=1 $, $ S $ is a surface.

When $ f(x,y)\ne 1 $, $ S $ is a volume and $ f(x,y)dxdy $ is the elementary volume with $ dxdy$ as a base surface and $ f(x,y)$ as its height.